# C# Equivalent to java's Graphics2D

Tags: c#, c, graphics2d

I've recently started about thinking about making a 2D game engine in C# from scratch.

Now, I've wondered: In java, I'd use the java.awt.Graphics2d and java.awt.Container classes.

What would you suggest me to use in C#?

Apparently, google couldn't help me with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET you could use `Windows Presentation Foundation`, it offers a great lot of graphic-manipulation. But if it fits to create a game-engine, I am not sure.
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742562.aspx) for an overview.

Though, if you really want to have power, you should stick with [`DirectX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) and C++.

Note: there is [FNA](https://fna-xna.github.io/) and [MonoGame](https://www.monogame.net/) (both reimplementations of the now discontinued [XNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)), but they are both frameworks for creating games, not creating a game engine...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily build games (2D/3D) with FNA or MonoGame (reimplementations of the now discontinued XNA). They aren't engines but they are both a layer architecture for simple DirectX-usage.

If you're looking for image manipulation within Windows Forms (PictureBox, Draw()-method overrides) you should have a look at [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.aspx).